# Angular referencing controller from html without $scope

Tags: html, angularjs, scope, alias

I am working with the new angular, and as I was told - I am getting rid of the $scope object.

So when I reference my controller from the html page I am referencing it using alias:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController as ctrl">
    <p>{{ ctrl.Hello }}</p>
</div>
```

My question is: when I'm using routes and I declare one of my routes as:

```
$stateProvider.state('myPage', {
  url: "/myPage",
  templateUrl: "./views/myPage.html",
  controller: 'MyController'
  })
```

What is the appropriate way to reference the controller in such case without using a $scope?

Comment: `controller: 'MyController as myCtrl'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ui-router supports the `controllerAs` with a property.

```
$stateProvider.state('myPage', {
  url: "/myPage",
  templateUrl: "./views/myPage.html",
  controller: 'MyController',
  controllerAs: 'ctrl'
})
```

More information
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki

Comment: If using a string you can also use `controller: 'MyController as ctrl'`

Answer (score 1):

Use your controller with the "controller as" syntax and the vm variable:

```
function MyController() {
    // VM represents the View’s Model (aka ViewModel)
    var vm = this;

   // exports
   vm.item = "Test item";

   return vm;
}
```

- Create a controller without $scope.
- Assign `this` to a local variable. I preferred variable name as vm, you can choose any name of your choice.
- Attach data and behaviour to the `vm` variable.
- On the `view`, give an alias to the controller using the controller as syntax.
- You can give any name to the alias. I prefer to use vm unless I’m not working with nested controllers.